# Jquery LIVE, with an append, is breaking the MouseOver

Tags: jquery, append, bind, live

Here's the code:

```
<p>Morbi vitae erat. Cras sem lorem, porta ut, aliquam id, porta sed, velit.
Pellentesque scelerisque erat rhoncus nulla. <span class="findme">find me</span>Integer pulvinar, est ut</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.findme').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
        if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            // do something on mouseover
            $(this).css("background", "red");
            $(this).append('<span id="dropdown">XXX</span>');
        } else {
            // do something on mouseout
            $(this).css("background", "transparent");
            $('#dropdown').remove();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

I want a dropdown element to appear next to the next, to allow the user to change a setting when they move their mouse over. Problem is that when the mouse rolls over the XXX, it triggers a the mouseout, even though it's inside the .findme Any ideas why that is? Or a better way to accomplish this effect?

Comment: Can you host an example of this?

Comment: I don't have a server. I'm using 1.4.2

Comment: There are free web hosts. Make it happen.

Comment: +1, I also met this stangely problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is the standard behavior of `mouseout`. If you are using jQuery 1.4 then you should replace mouseover / mouseout with mouseenter / mouseleave.

EDIT:
Some example code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.findme').live('mouseenter', function(event) {
        $(this).css("background", "red");
        $(this).append('<span id="dropdown">XXX</span>');
    }).live('mouseleave', function(event) {
        $(this).css("background", "transparent");
        $('#dropdown').remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you show an exmaple, I I'm trying that but it doesn't work

Comment: Post an example of this issue. There's a 90% chance you're doing something wrong on your page, and without posting what you've actually got in a way that's easy to view, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: It's in an iframe, can that be the problem?

Comment: Can you put an example up at http://jsbin.com  

For example: http://jsbin.com/utodi3

Answer (score 0):

Try using mouseenter and mouseleave.

```
.live({
    mouseenter:
       function()
       {

       },
    mouseleave:
       function()
       {

       }
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working correctly:

```
$(".findme").mouseenter(function(){
    // do something on mouseover
    $(this).css("background", "red");
    $(this).append('<span id="dropdown">edit</span>');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    // do something on mouseout
    $(this).css("background", "transparent");
    $('#dropdown').remove();
});
```

Hopefully this helps others with a similar need.

Comment: You might as well accept this answer, so that others can tell you've solved the problem.